# How to modify pinned clipboard items outside the clipboard popup?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, clipboard

By default, when you copy a text (for example called x), then copy another text (called y) to the Windows clipboard, the second item (y) replaces the first item (x). So better to say, only one item at the same time can be stored in the clipboard. Since Windows 10, a new feature was added to Windows: **Clipboard History**; Which lets you copy & keep multiple things to the clipboard at the same time. According to [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6#:%7E:text=To%20get%20to%20your%20clipboard%20history%2C%20press%20Windows%20logo%20key%C2%A0%2B%20V.), Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> will open the clipboard history popup.

[Clipboard History popup in Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBZnC.png)

Also, there's an option for each item in the history to pin them. According to [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/clipboard-in-windows-c436501e-985d-1c8d-97ea-fe46ddf338c6#:%7E:text=Pinning%20an%20item%20keeps%20it%20from%20being%C2%A0removed%20from%20the%20clipboard%20history%C2%A0to%20make%20room%20for%20new%20items.):

> Pinning an item keeps it from being removed from the clipboard history to make room for new items.

[Pinning in Windows 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkqyz.png)

Also, pinning an item will make it stay even after the computer's restart, so *I guess* that the item must be saved on the hard disk, not RAM.

Is that correct? If yes, is there a way to modify the pinned items outside the clipboard popup (add, edit, or remove them)?

Comment: Your question seems entirely independent of all the 5 paragraph pre-amble… Best way to modify a clipboard item has always been 'paste, modify, re-copy'. Note: 'clipboard' may not only be a bit of text, a good clipboard will be context sensitive… copy an image file, then paste to a text document you get the title, but paste to an image editor you get the picture. It's just not all that simple.